# ERROR 404 when form method=post

Tags: forms, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a form I want to sent to the google api to create a chart:

```
<form action='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart' method='POST'>
<input type="hidden" name="cht" value="lc"  />
<input type="hidden" name="chtt" value="Yeast Density"  />
<input type='hidden' name='chs' value='300x200' />
<input type="hidden" name="chxt" value="x,y" />
<input type="hidden" name="chxl" value="0:|0|1|5|10|15|20|25|" />
<input name='chd' value='t:0,2,20,10,0'/>
<input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

Each time I click submit I get an error 404 message.
Strangely the same site works outside WordPress, I also checked the list of reserved words within wordpress, but non of these appears to be conflicting with my variables. What causes the problem?

Comment: I removed your dead links

Answer (score 1):

Add an `action` attribute to your form with a value of `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart`.

```
<form id="form1" action="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart">
```

Unless you're using HTML5, I'd also recommend you explicitly set the `method` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your link I see:

```
<form id=​"form1">​
```

No action attribute set.

Comment: There are two forms, the second one should be sent, the first one is only gathering data for the second one